# Flex++ Bisonc++ parser

Tags: c++, parsing, bison, flex-lexer

I'm trying to use `flex` and `bison` in my project to generate a parser code for a file structure. Main programming language is C++ and project is on an OO design mainly running in parallel.

I heard that `flex` and `bison` generated parsers are C codes and they're not reenterant. Googling, I found `flex++` and `bisonc++`. Unfortunately there is no simple tutorial to get started. Most examples are based on `bison/flex`. Some people somehow integrated `bison/flex` parsers in their C++ code. They supposed to be "tricky"...

Documentation of `flex++` and `bisonc++` doesn't help me and. Tutorials and examples, they all get input from stdin and print some messages on stdout.

I need these features in my parser:

1. Parser should be a C++ class, defined in normal manner (a header and a cpp file)
2. Parser receives data from either an `std::string` or `std::stringstream` or a null-terminated `char*`.

I feel so confused. Should I use `flex++/bisonc++` or `flex/bison`? And how to do that, satisfying above conditions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are flex/bison, flex++/bison++ and flexc++/bisonc++. I think it's best to pick one of these three pairs, instead of mixing/matching flex++ and bisonc++.
Here are the user guides for [Flexc++](http://flexcpp.sourceforge.net/flexc++.html) and [Bisonc++](http://bisoncpp.sourceforge.net/bisonc++.html).

From the Flexc++ website:

> Flexc++, contrary to flex and flex++, generates code that is
>   explicitly intended for use by C++ programs. The well-known flex(1)
>   program generates C source-code and flex++(1) merely offers a C++-like
>   shell around the yylex function generated by flex(1) and hardly
>   supports present-day ideas about C++ software development.
>   Contrary to this, flexc++ creates a C++ class offering a predefined
>   member function lex matching input against regular expressions and
>   possibly executing C++ code once regular expressions were matched. The
>   code generated by flexc++ is pure C++, allowing its users to apply all
>   of the features offered by that language.

From the Bisonc++ website:

> Bisonc++ is a general-purpose parser generator that converts a grammar
>   description for an LALR(1) context-free grammar into a C++ class to
>   parse that grammar. Once you are proficient with bisonc++, you may use
>   it to develop a wide range of language parsers, from those used in
>   simple desk calculators to complex programming languages. Bisonc++ is
>   highly comparable to the program bison++, written by Alain Coetmeur:
>   all properly-written bison++ grammars ought to be convertible to
>   bisonc++ grammars after very little or no change. Anyone familiar with
>   bison++ or its precursor, bison, should be able to use bisonc++ with
>   little trouble. You need to be fluent in using the C++ programming in
>   order to use bisonc++ or to understand this manual.

So flexc++/bisonc++ are more than just wrappers around the old flex/bison utilities. They generate complete C++ classes to be used for re-entrant scanning / parsing.

Comment: I even can't compile flexc++! Just downloaded source code. No makefile, no cmake  nothing!

Comment: @sorush-r there's a Linux package: http://packages.debian.org/sid/flexc++ Why would you need a makefile? Just include the headers and build from your own environment.

Comment: I didn't heard about `icmake` before. seems to be the build system used to compile `flexc++`. Thanks

Comment: @sorush-r The author Frank Brokken makes a lot of his own utilities. Apart from flexc++, bisonc++, icmake he also did a markup language (yodl) and much more. Oh and he is the author of the C++ Annations document http://cppannotations.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I'm compiling `flexc++`. Hope can use it successfully!
I really like C++ Annations a lot! It's my main resource for cpp. In fact I always do `sudo apt-get install c++-annotations-pdf` ;) It has a section for bisonc++/flex (last section in book) Unfortunately it's so complicated for me.

Comment: @sorush-r If you mean section 23.9 http://www.icce.rug.nl/documents/cplusplus/cplusplus23.html#l576, that's the one. If you follow this line by line, you should get a compilable example by the time you reach 23.9.2.

Comment: I'll take a look at (4th time!). I think all stuff about `lex`, `flex`, `yacc`, `flex`, `bison`, etc, are very complicated. started to study about two weeks ago, since now, no success. yet!

Comment: @sorush-r Perseverance will pay off for you, just try to understand one step at the time. I had the good fortune to be a student at the same university where Frank Brokken was a teacher, at the time when the Annotations were being written! That was even before the old C++98 standard was ready, with broken compilers etc. But somehow, I got through that class. Now it's a lot easier, so good luck to you!

Answer (score 2):

Flex can generate a reentrant C scanner.  See Section [19 Reentrant C scanners](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Reentrant.html) in the Flex manual.

Similarly, Bison can generate a reentrant C parser.  See Section [3.8.11 A Pure (Reentrant) Parser](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Pure-Decl) in the Bison manual for details.

Do you absolutely need to have a C++ parser and std::string/stringstream based parser data?

Have you looked at [Boost.Spirit](http://boost-spirit.com/) as an alternative?

Comment: No. I can change my code to generate `char*`s to be parsed. Bu not able to read input from `stdin`

Comment: @sorush-r:  You should be able to change the source of your Flex C scanner input by redefining the `YY_INPUT()` macro.  See [Section 9 The Generated Scanner](http://flex.sourceforge.net/manual/Generated-Scanner.html#Generated-Scanner) in the Flex manual.  I'd take a serious look at Boost.Spirit, too.

Answer (score 0):

The [LRSTAR product](http://lrstar.tech) (LR(k) parser and DFA lexer generator) is C++ based. Runs on Widowns and has six Visual Studio projects. The code also compiles with "gcc" and other compilers. There are classes for lexer and parser, symbol-table, AST.  Complete source code is available. It gets good reviews.  I should know.  I am the author.